# How can the attributes of outer class can be accesed within the inner class in Composition Classes design?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, composition

I am totally unable to access the outer class attributes inside the inner class ...
even if i make object of outer class,, in inner class**which makes no sense in composition design** .. even then i cant access them .. 
is there a way by which i can access these outer class attributes ?

Scenario is that there is some sports car which is constructed only if the customers who want to buy it exists! ..

```
namespace composition{
public class CustomCar
{
    #region Attributes
    private string name;
    private string plateno;
    private double cost;
    private CarCustomer _customer = new CarCustomer();

    #endregion

    #region properties

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public double Cost
    {
        get { return cost; }
        set { cost = value; }
    }


    public string PlateNo
    {
        get { return plateno; }
        set { plateno = value; }
    }



    public CarCustomer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set { _customer = value; }
    }


    #endregion

    #region methods

    public CustomCar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in custom car");
    }



    public CustomCar(string s1, string pno, double c, string s2, double n, double bc)
    {
        this.Name = s1;
        this.PlateNo = pno;
        this.Cost = c;
        this.Customer.Name1 = s2;
        this.Customer.Nic1 = n;
        this.Customer.BargainCost = bc;
    }

    public double finalCost()
    {
        if (this.Customer.BargainCost < 10000)
        {
            double FinalCost = (this.Cost - this.Customer.BargainCost);
            return FinalCost;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Cost;
        }

    }

    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.name + this.PlateNo + this.Customer.Name1 + this.Customer.Nic1);
    }

    #endregion


    public class CarCustomer
    {
        private string name1;
        private double Nic;
        private double bargainCost;


        public double BargainCost
        {
            get { return bargainCost; }
            set { bargainCost = value; }
        }

        public double Nic1
        {
            get { return Nic; }
            set { Nic = value; }
        }


        public string Name1
        {
            get { return name1; }
            set { name1 = value; }
        }

        public CarCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I have a customer");
        }

        public CarCustomer(string n1, double i1, double bc)
        {
            this.Name1 = n1;
            this.Nic = i1;
            this.BargainCost = bc;
        }

        public void showCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer name:   " + Name1);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer NIC:    " + Nic1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you having a reference in the CarCustomer to the CustomCar object as well.  This would then give you a one to one reference between the object.  Were you instaiate this object is up to you in the Constructor of the CustomCar

```
public CustomCar(arguments)
{
    this.Customer.CustomCar = this;
}
```

Or you could set it in the sets on the property accessors up to you.  Try this

```
public class CustomCar
{
    private string name;
    private string plateno;
    private double cost;
    private CarCustomer _customer = new CarCustomer();

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public double Cost
    {
        get { return cost; }
        set { cost = value; }
    }


    public string PlateNo
    {
        get { return plateno; }
        set { plateno = value; }
    }



    public CarCustomer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
        set { _customer = value; }
    }

    public CustomCar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in custom car");
    }



    public CustomCar(string name, string pno, double c, string customerName, double n, double bc)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.PlateNo = pno;
        this.Cost = c;
        this.Customer.Name1 = customerName;
        this.Customer.Nic1 = n;
        this.Customer.BargainCost = bc;
        this.Customer.Car = this;
    }

    public double finalCost()
    {
        if (this.Customer.BargainCost < 10000)
        {
            double FinalCost = (this.Cost - this.Customer.BargainCost);
            return FinalCost;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Cost;
        }

    }

    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.name + this.PlateNo + this.Customer.Name1 + this.Customer.Nic1);
    }
}

    public class CarCustomer
    {
        private string name1;
        private double Nic;
        private double bargainCost;
        private CustomCar customer;

        public double BargainCost
        {
            get { return bargainCost; }
            set { bargainCost = value; }
        }

        public double Nic1
        {
            get { return Nic; }
            set { Nic = value; }
        }       


        public string Name1
        {
            get { return name1; }
            set { name1 = value; }
        }

        public CustomCar Car
        {
            get{return customer;}
            set{customer = value;}
        }

        public CarCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I have a customer");
        }

        public CarCustomer(string n1, double i1, double bc)
        {
            this.Name1 = n1;
            this.Nic = i1;
            this.BargainCost = bc;                  
        }

        public void showCustomer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Customer name:   " + Name1);
            Console.WriteLine("Customer NIC:    " + Nic1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Feanz: this is giving a compile error! .. not the right solution!

Comment: @Sana.91 what compile error? I assume you did not just copy and paste it.

Comment: i tried to do above thing in both ctors .. the comiler is not sensing customer.customcar thru its intelliSens and is giving error

Comment: this.Customer.Car = this;          
There is no attribute like Car in my code!

Comment: Heyyyy I got this .. Thanks a lot .. :) outer class attributes Now accessible; But can you please explain the line: ???

                     this.Customer.Car = this;

Comment: The this.Customer.Car = this; line simply sets the CustomCar property on the customer object equal to the CustomCar that you are constructing.  This mean that when you construct a customcar you will always associate it with one specific customer.  And the customer will be associated with the car.

Comment: Feanz: Does this thing violate Composition?

Comment: @Sana.91 no it's fairly standard OO pattern with a 1.1 association

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can't access them. You've set their protection level to `private`. In order to get  at them from an external resource their protection level has to be in line with the access level needed. In this case you should be able to change the modifier to `protected` and be able to access them.

However, looking at your class design, I think you would be better served using the automatic getter/setter syntax. You aren't doing anything particularly special in your property definitions, so it would make sense to get rid of the private variables and change your properties to this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public double Cost { get; set; }
public string PlateNo { get; set; }
public CarCustomer Customer  { get; set; }
```

You'll still have public access to the variables through the properties and you won't have all the messiness of the extra variables.

Comment: Joel Etherton: I still cant access .. its a compostition Design , not inheritance

Comment: @Sana.91: Yes, but the rules are still the same. I don't see any attempts in the code you posted to perform any such access. Perhaps if you showed what you're trying that is failing it would shed some light on the problem. It sounds as if you're attempting to access the properties without using a direct instance reference. Because of the composition nature of the design, you must still have an instance reference to get to those attributes.

Comment: if i have an instance of customCar in carcustomer and then try to access outer class attribute .. "process terminated due to stackoverflowexception is encountered"

Comment: @Sana.91: Yes because you'll have a CustomCar with a CarCustomer that has the CustomCar that has a CarCustomer that has the CustomCar --- basically you're creating an endless loop (thus the overflow). You need to use a method rather than a property, and you must not ever attempt to access the CarCustomer object through the CustomCar object as that will create the circular references all over again. Given this structure, I would question the purpose of actually having this need in the first place. This exception is usually an indication that your usage is improperly placed.

Comment: Joel Etherton: So no way to access outer class attributes?

Comment: @Sana.91: They're reference based. How would the inner class have any idea WHICH car they referred to? In the composite design vs. inheritance, the composite is simply behaving as a namespace container. The class itself is not available outside of the scope of the containing class. There is no natural or implied relationship between the classes. If the attributes were static they would be accessible, but then they would be the same for all instances of the CustomCar class.

Comment: How can u implement this scenario in c# then ? ... **A car that is no constructed untill a customer orders for it ...???**
This simply mean that
a) for the car to be constructed , its customer should exist
b) customer is "a-part" of the car

Composition design is best here right?

Comment: Provide a constructor that accepts a valid CarCustomer, then assigns itself to that CarCustomer to the property. If you have various types of cars then you can provide an enumeration such that if a particular type of car is called in the Constructor and it doesn't meet the requirements then fail with an exception.